# how to fetch a new image from api after one click vanilla.js

Tags: javascript, button, fetch-api

I'm trying to figure out a better way to fetch a new image when clicking my button.
here is my code:

```
function getPizzaHtml(pizza) {
    return `
    <div class="header">Random Pizzas </div>
    <button id="show-pizza-btn">Click Me</button>
    <div class="pizza-image">
    <img class="pizza-images" style="display: none" src="${pizza.image}"/>
    </div>
    `
}



getPizzaImg().then(pizza => {
    console.log(pizza)
    document.body.innerHTML = getPizzaHtml(pizza);
    let pizzaBtn = document.getElementById('show-pizza-btn');
    pizzaBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let pizzaImg = document.querySelector('.pizza-images');
        if(pizzaImg.style.display === 'none') {
            pizzaImg.style.display = 'inline'
        } else {
            window.location.reload();
        } 
    })
})
```

with the if-statement, I can fetch a new image since it reloads the page and so reloads the fetch. But, in order for it to appear, I have to click it twice.

I appreciate all advice and help!

Answer (score 0):

You can change `pizzaImg.src` to change the image. You can change your event listener to something like this:

```
pizzaBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let pizzaImg = document.querySelector('.pizza-images');
    if(pizzaImg.style.display === 'none') {
        pizzaImg.style.display = 'inline'
    } else {
        getPizzaImg().then(newPizza => pizzaImg.src = newPizza.image)
    } 
})
```